# Could CPA lasers be used to produce a Pure Fusion Weapon?

Tags: nuclear-physics, laser, fusion, non-linear-optics

In particular, has there been any experimental testing of using the [Chirped Pulse Amplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirped_pulse_amplification) (CPA) technique to ignite a fusion pellet in the first place. If so, have any of the experiments yielded successful ignition? The reason is that CPA lasers can be built to be highly compact (necessary for building such a device).

Comment: have a look  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_(laser)

Comment: Yeah anna v I saw that. That thing is a dinosaur nowadays! I was asking about some more recent advances in CPA compactification.

Comment: maybe it means it has been superceded  as an idea?  seev https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility  also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_laser

Comment: See also about HiPER, the successor of Nova. Meant to use CPA, in a smaller footprint. Not clear from article the current status. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiPER

Comment: Anyway, a pure fusion weapon might be of some value, but not clear that there would be any practical gain from today's' fusion-fission bombs, which are plenty deliverable. The value of CPA in fusion would be of immense value for continuous fusion, if they're able to solve all the issues they've always run into. And magnetic confinement fusion is still competitive.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible to use high-powered lasers to initiate fusion. The state of the art in that regard is the [National Ignition Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility) in the US (though they don't use CPA; the largest laser that uses it, to my knowledge, was [Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_(laser)), with a larger device currently in construction at [ELI Beamlines](https://www.eli-beams.eu/en/facility/) if I understand correctly), but they look to be a ways away from actual ignition, and current experiments use more energy than they produce.

However, your statement that

> CPA lasers can be built to be highly compact

is correct, but it doesn't apply to the high-power devices that can be used for inertial-confinement fusion experiments. If you have a single CPA beamline and you only want a 'modest' amount of power in it (i.e. enough for XUV/x-ray generation, but not for inertial-confinement fusion), then it can be built to be "fairly compact", but what that means is that it will fit on a single optical table. However, if you want to hurl it through the sky at supersonic speeds (or indeed do anything other than keep it on a stabilized optical table on a building with solid foundations and no significant noise sources around) then you can kiss your laser alignment goodbye.

That's for a single beamline, though. To initiate fusion, the (non-CPA) NIF uses 192 beamlines, and it looks something like this:

[image]

(As such, it resembles a 'weapon' about as much as the [Ivy Mike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Mike) device did, which is to say: not much.)

This can in principle be miniaturized to fit inside a warhead, but that's not going to happen anytime that's even remotely, conceivably soon.

Comment: Maybe worth drawing explicit attention to the human in the figure to help establish the scale. Also, I'm fairly sure this image is public domain or released under a permissive license (I used it in a presentation for class at one point), but it never hurts to be explicit.

Comment: dmckee: That is unnecessary. Their yellow hard hats stand out quite nicely.